# R - add string to list

Tags: r

if have a vector (given) of words and I want to add the words to another vector, when a string starts with a vowel:

```
given = c("abc","def","oba") 
expected=c("abc","oba")
```

I use the following code in R:

```
expected=""
given = c("abc","def","oba")


for (i in  1:length(given)){
  start=substring(given[i], 1, 1)
  if(start == "a" ||start == "e"|| start == "i" ||start == "o" ||start == "u")
  {
  expected[i]<-given[i]

  }
  else
  {
    ""
  }
}
```

The out is:

```
[1] "abc" NA    "oba
```

And I wanted to have

```
[1] "abc" "oba
```

Can anyone help me to have a vector created without the NA?

How would I do that with a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `grepl` here:

```
given <- c("abc", "def", "oba")
expected <- given[grepl("^[aeiou]", given, ignore.case=TRUE)]
expected

[1] "abc" "oba"
```

The regex pattern `^[aeiou]` will match any string beginning with a vowel letter (either uppercase or lowercase).

Comment: Works perfect. Can you help me why in my code R adds the NA? It has to to with loop, why is it not exiting the loop but adding a NA

Comment: The issue is that your current script only makes assigments to `expected[1]` and `expected[3]`.  The second slot never gets assigned a value, so it defaults to `NA`.  You could fix that by keeping a second index used to assign to `expected`, but this would not be canonical R coding.  Use `grepl` and make your life easier.